# How to make sure my security and authentication mechanism in Rails is safe enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, devise

I'm using Rails 4 to build my site. I want function A to be authenticated to user X, function B to user Y and the other functions to all users. Currently I'm implementing security and authentication mechanism by setting user model and sessions.

I don't want the data in my rails application to be accessed by those who not authenticated. My problem is I'm not sure my mechanism is safe enough because I cannot sure if I have thought all the circumstances thoroughly. It is harmful if I could find the system not safe only when the system is hacked. How to make sure and test it is safe enough?

Or should I use the well-known gem `Devise` instead of implementing my authentication mechanism? I know using a open source project will lead to a issue that everyone knows how your security and authentication mechanism works, but the validity of the `Devise` should be tested by many users.

Comment: Yes, you should use the off-the-shelf solution that has been *massively* peer-reviewed and battled hardened by thousands upon thousands of installations. Every time.

Comment: If you want to know if your own code is secure share the source and ask for a peer review BEFORE you let it go live.  Also, you wouldn't be the first to pay someone to hack your system just to see if they can.

Answer (score 2):

> I know using a open source project will lead to a issue that everyone
>   knows how your security and authentication mechanism works

System security should not depend on the secrecy of the implementation or its components.

Use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) paired with [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and test thoroughly ([rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails)) and you'll be fine.

Comment: +1 for secrecy comment.  Security through obscurity is a bad practice.  Hide your private keys not your algorithms.

Comment: My concern is there could be a un-reported bug in such gem and someone find and exploit it.

Comment: Unless you are a rails and security expert, the chance is you'll also have a vulnerability in your code. At least devise is being scrutinised by thousands of people. If it has a vulnerability it will be found and fixed.